# Neo4j order by relationship count

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I'm new to neo4j and tried to implement a graph with some success.
Now I'm trying to make a query ordered by the number of relationships.

For example.

```
START n=node(*) MATCH (n->[r]->()) ORDER BY Count(r)
```

is this the right syntax and how do I fire of this question in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query can be like that

```
START n=node(*) MATCH n-[r]->()
 RETURN n, r, count(r) 
 ORDER BY count(r)
```

And you can simply use REST appi to fire the query and execute it in java code..  This link may help you  [Execute Cypher Queries from Java](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html)